# MATLAB Sum along some columns within 3D matrix

Tags: matlab

Let's assume I have a `8x6x2` matrix `signals`. I would like to sum along the columns excluding the first column. When using the following code, MATLAB concatenates the 3D matrix to a big 2D (`8x11`) matrix, which is different from the result I am looking for.

```
sum(signals(:, 2:end), 2)
```

I am actually looking for a `8x1x2` 3D vector comprising the sums of column 2 to six from each third dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your matrix is a 3D matrix, you need to include a colon as the third subscript in your indexing. If you only specify two subscripts, then MATLAB will collapse all trailing dimensions into the last dimension you've specified.

```
sum(signals(:, 2:end, :), 2)
```

Comment: @Suever...You're right, I just figured it out after hitting the send button. Sometimes it's that easy. Thanks!